OpenAi api | How can I answer a question with an "uploaded" PDF
I’m working on a Python project where I use OpenAI's GPT-4 API to analyze data from screenshots and PDFs.
My goal is to send the request with the screenshot and the PDF (Both in a single request) to the gpt-4 api.
The part with the screenshot sending works and I get no errors when I also attach the pdf. But it does not take into account anything written in that PDF.
Here are the relevant parts of the code:
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

def encode_pdf_to_base64(pdf_path):
    """
    Encodes PDF to base64
    """
    try:
        with open(pdf_path, "rb") as pdf_file:
            return base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read()).decode('utf-8')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: The file '{pdf_path}' was not found.")
        return None

def analyze_with_pdf_and_screenshot(screenshot_path, pdf_path=None):
    """
    Analyzes the Screenshot with the help of the PDF
    """
    base64_image = encode_image(screenshot_path)
    base64_pdf = encode_pdf_to_base64(pdf_path) if pdf_path else None


        payload = {
            "model": "gpt-4o",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "Analyze the given Screenshot with the help of the attached PDF and answer with its help"
                        },
                        # Also tried this one and it didnt work
                        #{ 
                        #    "type": "file",
                        #    "file": {
                        #        "name": os.path.basename(pdf_path),
                        #        "type": "application/pdf",
                        #        "content": base64_pdf
                        #    }
                        #},
                        {
                            "type": "image_url",
                            "image_url": {
                                "url": f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64_image}"
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                    "files": [
                        {
                            "name": os.path.basename(pdf_path),
                            "type": "application/pdf",
                            "content": base64_pdf
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "max_tokens": 2500
        }

    try:
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"
        }
        response = requests.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", headers=headers, json=payload)
        response.raise_for_status()
        result = response.json()
        print("API-Answer:", json.dumps(result, indent=2))  
        return ""

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error analyzing file: {e}")
        return ""


This question is similar to: How can I process a pdf using OpenAI's APIs (GPTs)?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
